# How to specify the units of a variable in \tikzmath or argument of a \newcommand that uses pgfkeys

Tags: macros, pgfkeys, tikzmath

I would like to specify the units of an argument of a `\newcommand` that uses `pgfkeys` and that goes into a `\tikzmath` enviroment as a variable as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfkeys{
 /myfam/.is family, /myfam,
  default/.style = {length = 10cm},
  length/.estore in = \mylen,
 }

\newcommand{\myline}[1][]{
\pgfkeys{/myfam, default, #1}
\tikzmath{
 real \mylen, \mylennew;
 \mylennew = \mylen+1;   % do some math operation here
}
\draw (0,0) -- (\mylennew, \mylennew);   % this will specify the units as cm
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myline[length=1] % the argument has no units here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the above, `\myline[length=1]` results the variable in the `\draw` command have units in `cm`.

My questions are:

1. Right after the `\tikzmath` enviroment, how can I specify the units of the variable `\mylennew` in the `\draw` command; may be something like:

   ```
   \draw (0,0) -- (\mylennew cm, \mylennew pt);
   ```
2. If I would like to do something like `\myline[length=1cm]` or `\myline[length=1pt]`, it does not give the result that I want. How can I specify the units with the arguments of `\newcommand` that uses `pgfkeys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that, tikzmath converts any variable with centimeter (or milimeter) unit to corresponding point values (1 cm = 28.45274 pt) without keeping the unit (i.e. point). This is what happens within Tikzmath block:

```
\x = 1cm;
\newx = \x;  %\newx has a value of 28.45274
```

I am guessing that this is related to Tex math engine as well?

I provide two solutions on a different example:

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
    \usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

    \pgfkeys{
     /testfam/.is family, /testfam,
      default/.style={x = 1cm, y = 1},
      x/.estore in = \x, y/.estore in = \y}

    \newcommand{\testfam}[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{/testfam, default, #1}
    \tikzmath{
      real \x, \y, \newx, \newy; 
      coordinate \cd;
      \newx1 = \x;
      \newx2 = \x/28.45274;
      \newy = \y;
      \cd1 = (\newx1 pt,1 cm);
      \cd2 = (2 cm,1 cm);
      \cd3 = (\newx2 cm,2 cm);
      \cd4 = (2 cm,2 cm);    
      \cd5 = (4 cm,0 cm);
      \cd6 = (4 cm,\y cm);
      print {$x=\x $};
      print {$newx1=\newx1 $};  
      print {$newx2=\newx2 $};
      print {$y=\y $}
      print {$newy=\newy $};
    }

    \draw [line width = 1pt] (\cd1) -- (\cd2);

    \draw [line width = 1pt, color=blue] (\cd3) -- (\cd4);

    \draw [line width = 1pt, color=red] (\cd5) -- (\cd6);
    }

    \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \testfam[x = 1cm, y=1] %Two cases: with and without units, 
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```